# How to get time in '2022-12-01T09:13:45Z' this format?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# local datetime to ISO Datetime
iso_date = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
print('ISO Datetime:', iso_date)
```

This doesn't give me the required format i want

```
2022-05-18T13:43:13
```

I wanted to get the time like '2022-12-01T09:13:45Z'

Comment: You want a time with timezone information. so so use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`

Comment: @FObersteiner: new python support it, else: did yo unotice that the OP is using pytz? So no hack but you the pytz (for old python versions)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi how do you get "Z" for UTC with the standard library? Btw. pytz does not give you any formatting options for converting datetime to string, no?

Comment: When converting datetime to string, unfortunately, the Python standard library does not provide a built-in method that gives you 'Z' for UTC. You'll need to use one of the "hacks" (append literal Z for instance) below. Or use "+00:00" as a UTC specifier.

Comment: @FObersteiner: the code I wrote it copied directly from Python documentation. Before that there where the package `pytz` to handle timezones. With hacks in 2 months you will not known which variable is aware and which it naive, and so more problems. It is really better to take some more time and fix things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time format that you want is known as Zulu time format, the following code changes UTC to Zulu format.

**Example 1**

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
print(now)
```

Output

```
#2022-12-01 10:07:06.552326+00:00
```

**Example 2 (Hack)**

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
now = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')+ now.strftime('.%f')[:4]  + 'Z'
print(now)
```

Output

```
#2022-12-01T10:06:41.122Z
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Please no. Do not add `Z` to a string as timezone. It is an hack. Do properly and have a timezone aware date

Answer (score 0):

You can use datime's [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) function i.e.

```py
current_datetime = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
print(f'ISO Datetime: {current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")}')
```

Comment: `datetime.now()` does not give you UTC